# I need to customize the menu style for my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress

The following is the link to the wordpress site http://meridian.ink/ 
The theme has the menu button take up the whole page and have a list once you click on it. my boss wants it so that either its just a horizontal menu when you click the menu button or the elements are already listed horizontally. the problem is I cant seem to find a way to change just the theme of the menu. I've tried plugins like mega max menu and menubar but I can't seem to change it. Any link, code, answer/ advice would be appreciated. Than you.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide an image / draft of how you'd graphically like to make it look like?

Applying a set of CSS rules to the popup could help moving the menu to the top. If you have access to the code itself, it should be the preffered way to change it there.

**Example CSS Rules**

```
filter-list.open, .menu-filter-type.open {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
    bottom: auto;
}
.filter-list.open nav ul, .menu-filter-type.open nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
.filter-list.open nav .x-filter, .menu-filter-type.open nav .x-filter {
    display: none;
}
```

Note that these are just an example and may not be useful in production.

Hope I could help!